# DotNetOpenauth: MVC WebSite As Resource Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to create a resource server on ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Site. Is there any sample related to this.

My main goal is to secure MVC View on a Resource Server using another  OAuth2.0 Authentication server...

Answer (score 1):

DotNetOpenAuth project has a sample ResourceServer written in ASP.NET (Web Forms not MVC)

The source is located here: https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/tree/master/samples/OAuthResourceServer